# How to give html tab title to ngb-bootstrap tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap as a substitute for ui-bootstrap in angular2.

My html is as follows:

```
<ngb-tabset class="tabs-bordered">
        <ngb-tab index="0">
          <ngb-tab-heading><i class="bi_doc-briefcase-a"></i> My jobs</ngb-tab-heading>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <ngb-tabset>
              <ngb-tab heading="Recommendations">
.........
```

I tryied `ngb-tab-title` as well but it is giving error as follows:

```
main.browser.ts:25Error: Template parse errors:
'ngb-tab-heading' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-tab-heading' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-tab-heading' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

............
```

I had declared my module and component as follows:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  imports: [NgbModule],
})

@Component({
  selector: 'myProfile',
  styles: [`
  `],
  template: template
})
```

Comment: add your module and component

Comment: Check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/G6zS6OEXQjjIOHTNmYGy?p=preview

Comment: By the way I don't see in the docs the ngb-tab-heading element

Comment: Same here but there was an element like ui-tab-heading element in ui-bootstrap

Comment: Your using Angular 2 now so check the docs.

Comment: The ngb-tab expect title Input

Comment: Yea but in title we cannot give html string, but any way thanks the plunker link given by you worked. :)

Comment: You can use  <template ngbTabTitle><b>Fancy</b> title</template>

Comment: Yes friend using template tag it worked as shown in plunker. You can post the answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working plunker:
[NgbModule tabs example](http://plnkr.co/edit/G6zS6OEXQjjIOHTNmYGy?p=preview)

If you need to use html content in your title you can use:

```
<template ngbTabTitle><b>Fancy</b> title</template>
```

Comment: Hi, In the [NgbModule tabs example](http://plnkr.co/edit/G6zS6OEXQjjIOHTNmYGy?p=preview) that you shared above, I find _ngb-tab_ elements listed as bullet-ed list. Why is that so? I was facing same issue and finally had to use ngx-bootstrap tab. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I don't see any title text for second tab which is configured as _<template ngbTabTitle><b>Fancy</b> title</template>_. It just shows a bullet with no content.